# Foreach with data from the viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Below is my code.

**Model**

```
public class ShiftsModel
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string xmlPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xml");

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        var shifts = (from b in xml.Descendants("Shift")
                      select new ShiftsModel
                     {
                         UID = (string)b.Attribute("UID"),
                         Date = (string)b.Element("Date"),
                         Time = (string)b.Element("Time"),
                         Location = (string)b.Element("Location")
                     }).ToList();

        return View(shifts);
    }

}
```

I'd now like to reference this in my Index.cshtml file like so:

```
@foreach(var shift in (List<object>ViewBag.shifts)) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" value="@(ViewBag.date)" }>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Shift time" value="@(ViewBag.time)" }>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" value="@(ViewBag.location)" }>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

However, I get an error on the `List<object>ViewBag.shifts` line saying:

> Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by
>   index.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong please? Thank you :)

Comment: As per the code you have give, `shifts` is the model, not in viewbag. Are you looking for @foreach(var shift in model) ?

Comment: You have not added anything to `ViewBag`. Add `@model List<ShiftsModel>` to the view and access the items using `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Date ..... }`

Comment: I guess, it's just a typo, change `(List<object>ViewBag.shifts)` to `(List<object>)Model.shifts`. If your view has not any model then add a proper strongly typed one (best) or declare it as `@model dynamic` (worse) or (better) `@model List<ShiftModel>` accessing with `foreach (var shift in Model)`

Comment: Thank you very much @AdrianoRepetti, I have changed that and now get the following error: `'System.Collections.Generic.List<OvertimeAvailability.Controllers.ShiftsModel>' does not contain a definition for 'shifts'`

Comment: @Nick see last part, you also need to change your foreach.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti, the foreach was changed. I'm really sorry if I'm being stupid here, but I tried adding both `@model List<ShiftModel>` and `@model Dynamic` to my Index.cshtml file and still get the same error.

Comment: @Nick do not worry! Just take a look to answers you already have, they show a complete working example!

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid using the ViewBag if possible since I don't understand it, but I don't understand the model method either so I'll give it a go :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can see you just don't pass your collection to View through `ViewBag` in your controller.

You should pass it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    var shifts = (from b in xml.Descendants("Shift")
                  select new ShiftsModel
                 {
                     UID = (string)b.Attribute("UID"),
                     Date = (string)b.Element("Date"),
                     Time = (string)b.Element("Time"),
                     Location = (string)b.Element("Location")
                 }).ToList();
    ViewBag.shifts = shifts; // this line will pass your object
    return View();
}
```

Then on your View:

```
    @foreach(var shift in (List<ShiftsModel>ViewBag.shifts)) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date"
                   value="@(shift.Date)" }>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Shift time"
                   value="@(shift.Time)" }>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"
                   value="@(shift.Location)" }>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

But MVC way to solve your problem is use Strongly typed View like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    var shifts = (from b in xml.Descendants("Shift")
                  select new ShiftsModel
                 {
                     UID = (string)b.Attribute("UID"),
                     Date = (string)b.Element("Date"),
                     Time = (string)b.Element("Time"),
                     Location = (string)b.Element("Location")
                 }).ToList();
    ViewData.Model = shifts; // this line will pass your object but now to model
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model List<ShiftsModel> @*this is where your model is defined on view*@


@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model[i].Date, new { placeholder = "Date" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model[i].Time, new { placeholder = "Shift time" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> Model[i].Location, new { placeholder = "Location" })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

You need `for` loop not `foreach` to solve MVC issues with array binding if you will post this model to the controller.

Comment: This is creating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate name attributes (without indexers) so would not bind to any model when submited.

Comment: @StephenMuecke agree, but it will solve OP first problem, i correct my answer

Comment: @StephenMuecke here you go

Comment: Thank you @teovankot, unfortunately I get this error: `CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` requires 1 type arguments'

Comment: @Nick did you add funn namespace to your shiftmodel class?

Comment: @teovankot you mean like this? `namespace OvertimeAvailability.Models
{
    public class ShiftsModel
    {`

Comment: @Nick yeap, in your view must be `@model List<OvertimeAvailability.Models.ShiftsModel> `

Comment: Thank you @teovankot, now I'm getting ` CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ShiftsModel' does not exist in the namespace 'OvertimeAvailability.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Nick Visual studio help you to add right namespace just write `List<ShiftsModel>` and check what it advise you

Comment: This line does not work     @foreach(var shift in (List<ShiftsModel>ViewBag.shifts)) {

Answer (score 1):

As teo van kot points out, you are not assigning your shifts to your viewbag.. But it is even better, and more appropriate to pass your ShiftsModel as the model and not via the ViewBag...
Make sure your Index.cshtml file has the following using statement:

```
@model IEnumerable<ShiftsModel>
```

And if you pass your model like you already did: `return View(shifts);` then you can iterate through your model like this:

```
@foreach(var shift in Model) 
{
   // do something with your shift
}
```